# Delete row in hive external table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I loaded text file into hive external table. That text file has a delimiter of `/` to differentiate column. Also additionally some column has new line character in one column. Because of that there is mismatch in the data stored in external table. In my case the unique key is `row_id` which contains values like `1_234` . `rowid` is numeric. But because of new line character in the text file, some rows has text in `row_id`.

Is there any way to delete those rows in hive or how can I remove the new line character in text file in hdfs?

Comment: How did you create the Hive table? `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/'`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a hadoop (streaming is an option) job to clean your data before loading into Hive.